# urllib2.urlopen I only get part of the web page

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib2, urlopen

Because `raptr` is closing sooner or later I want to save all my play data. I can access first tab but that's it. **How can I get data from 2nd, 3rd etc (It's at the bottom of the screen)?**

[image]

My code:

```
import urllib2
page = urllib2.urlopen('http://raptr.com/john/games')
data = []
for line in page:
    if "game\/" in line:
        data.append(line)

sorter = []

for i in data:
    sorter.append(i.split("game\/"))

games = []

for lst in sorter:
    for part in lst:
        if "game-title" in part:
            games.append(part)

for game in games:
    print(game)
```

P.S. I know about [file](http://raptr.com/my_playtime.json) but this file does't have all information I've uploaded to to the web page

Comment: Check if the URL is changing, on click of pages `2, 3, 4 etc.`! If it's changing then first of all grab all different URLs, store them in a list and do what you are doing currently for each value of list. If not then you have to crawl data on each navigation, that's a bit tricky.

Comment: It doesn't I checked. I don't know if I can change it through url. Someone that knows how web pages are built is needed.

Comment: Can you give the URL of the page, from where you took screenshot. I am not able to find it.

Comment: It's in code. Here you are http://raptr.com/john/games

Comment: Have you used Selenium? You can do it, using Selenium.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the library or service. It's library right?